# Как протестировать внутренний метод провайдера?

Tags: angularjs, юнит-тесты

Имеется провайдер

```
    angular.module('webConsole')
  .provider('$navbar', function(){

    return{

      // настройки провайдера
      configs: {
        apiUrl: '/api/',
        me: '/auth/me',
        server: '/srv/heartbeat'
      },



      //Метод конфигурирования провайдера
      configure : function (params) {
        var _this = this;
        if (params instanceof Object) {
          angular.extend(_this.configs, params);
        } else {
          throw new Exception("Argument exception: config params should be an Object");
        }
        return _this.configs;
      },
      $get: function($q, $http){
        return{};
      }
    };
  });
```

Метод configure это внутренний метод и используется только на этапе конфигурирования провайдера.

Я написал тест

```
describe('Тестируем navbar.provider.js', function(){

  var $navbarProvider, $navbar;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('webConsole', function(_$navbarProvider_){
      $navbarProvider = _$navbarProvider_
    })
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$navbar_) {
    $navbar = _$navbar_;
  }));

  describe('Тестируем методы', function(){

    it('Должен вернуть исключение, если передали не объект', function(){
      expect($navbarProvider.configure('string')).toThrow();
    });
  });
});
```

Тест не проходит по причине ошибки:

```
ReferenceError: Exception is not defined
```

Comment: Ну, во-первых, в js Error, а не Exception. Во-вторых, внутренние методы не должны тестироваться.

Comment: и в-третьих - это не внутренний метод, а вполне себе внешний :)